# Java: ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsExeption

Tags: java, indexoutofboundsexception

I created a program that should convert a 10 long int array to a "Phone number" format. For example like this:
Solution.createPhoneNumber(new int[] {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0}) // => returns "(123) 456-7890"

Here is my code:
Solution.java:

```
public class Solution {

    public static String createPhoneNumber(int[] numbers) {

        int counter = 0;

        char[] temp = new char[numbers.length + 4];

        temp[0] = '(';
        temp[4] = ')';
        temp[5] = ' ';
        temp[9] = '-';

        for (int i = 0 ; i < temp.length ; i++)
        {
            if (i!=0 && i!=4 && i!=5 && i!=9)
            {
                temp[i] = (char) numbers[counter];
                counter++;
            }

        }

        String solution = new String(temp);

        return solution;

    }
}
```

Test.java:

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int[] test = new int[10];

        test[0] = 1;
        test[1] = 2;
        test[2] = 3;
        test[3] = 4;
        test[4] = 5;
        test[5] = 6;
        test[6] = 7;
        test[7] = 8;
        test[8] = 9;
        test[9] = 0;

        System.out.println(Solution.createPhoneNumber(test));



    }

}
```

I get ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsExeption and I don't know why. In my test array I have 10 numbers, like in the example.

Comment: Please post the full stack trace.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Modify your loop like this:

```java
for (int i = 0 ; i < temp.length ; i++) {
    if (i!=0 && i!=4 && i!=5 && i!=9) {
        temp[i] = (char)(numbers[counter] + (int)'0');
        counter++;
    }
}
```

In your code, you increase the `counter` outside `if` condition, so `counter` may increase up to `temp.length` which is more than `numbers.length`, so `numbers[counter]` gives you exception.

And as @rzwitserloot said, you should replace `||` with `&&`

Comment: Thanks, it works now. My last problem is now it shows ? marks instead of the numbers, so I got this: (???) ???-????

Comment: That's because (char) x is not a character that represents an x, it's a character with code x. Use `temp[i] = (char)(numbers[counter] + (int)'0')` - so `temp[i]` becomes a character which code is by `numbers[counter]` more than code of character `'0'`.

Answer (score 1):

`if (i != 0 || i != 4)` is **always true**. If i is 0, then `i != 0` is a false term, but, `i != 4` is true, and `false || true` is true. Thus, always true, thus, counter always goes up, thus, it hits 10 and you run out of input digits.

Try using `&&` :)

Comment: The counter always goes up because `counter++` is not inside the `if` statement, anyway.